# redirecting external links to pages on my website

Tags: drupal, redirect, external, hardcoded

I am working on a project where I migrated content of an asp.net website into drupal nodes.This website had some hardcoded links in it.

Is there any module in drupal which can help me to do this?
Or can somebody suggest me a way about how to accomplish this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you migrated, why not just change the links then? You can always use JQuery (applied at a template or master page level) to change the links on the client side. But I don't understand why you dont just change them.

Answer (score 0):

This module should help, http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect